# MtGox money completely lost?

Tags: mtgox

Given the recent events and today's news about MtGox filing for *bankruptcy*, is my money on MtGox completely lost? and what are my options now?

Comment: news today eg yahoo [tokyo bitcoin exchange files for bankruptcy](http://news.yahoo.com/tokyo-bitcoin-exchange-files-bankruptcy-102841684--finance.html). the japanese govt (finance minister Taro Aso) is saying its not a real currency and that ppl should talk to their consumer affairs (protection?) agency.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on what the bankruptcy laws are in Japan and if the exchange has any assets or Bitcoins left.

Then it depends on how much the legal fees are involved it finding and converting all these into cash.

You should make sure you are included in the list of creditors or you will have no chance for a recovery of anything. And if you do recover, it will usually be pennies on the dollar.

Comment: How do you get included in the list of creditors?

Comment: I could tell you in the USA, but I do not know for Japan. I would start with a Google search of Japanese bankruptcy law.